# Avoid using "if" statements in JUnit5 Parameterized Test

Tags: java, unit-testing, testing, junit, mockito

I have a question regarding of the test below. I am testing my service class that:

- Takes a user request
- Checks if the email is present in the repository or not
- Creates a salt and a hash for password transformation
- Saves the user
- Calls the appropriate services according to the role provided in the initial request.

The Role class is an Enum that has the values CUSTOMER, TRAINER. My question has to do with the if statements I have used in my test. Is there any other way to write my test without using the "if" statements?

Previously I had two tests, each for one role but most the tests have duplicated code and I am trying to find a way to refactor them. Thank you for any advices.

```
    @ParameterizedTest
    @EnumSource(Role.class)
    @DisplayName("Create an application user and assign role correctly")
    public void givenUserRequest_whenCreateUser_thenAssignCorrectRole(Role role) {
        // given: the initial request
        CreateUserRequest request = createTestUserRequest(role);
        ApplicationUser user = createTestApplicationUser(role);

        // and: the user doesn't exist already with this email
        given(applicationUserRepo.findByEmail(request.getEmail())).willReturn(Optional.empty());

        // and: creating the password for this new user
        given(passwordCreation.createSalt()).willReturn(new byte[128]);
        given(passwordCreation.createPasswordHash(anyString(), any(byte[].class))).willReturn(new byte[64]);

        // and: save this new user
        given(applicationUserRepo.save(any(ApplicationUser.class))).willReturn(user);

        // and: depending on the role, the appropriate service is called
        UUID randomUUID = UUID.randomUUID();
        if (role == CUSTOMER) {
            given(customerService.createCustomer(any(ApplicationUser.class))).willReturn(randomUUID);
        } else {
            given(personalTrainerService.createTrainer(any(ApplicationUser.class))).willReturn(randomUUID);
        }

        // when: calling the service
        UUID savedUserUUID = service.createUser(request);

        // then: the user is being created
        assertThat(savedUserUUID).isEqualTo(randomUUID);

        // and: verify the expected parameters from initial request
        verify(applicationUserRepo).save(userCaptor.capture());
        ApplicationUser savedUser = userCaptor.getValue();
        assertThat(savedUser.getEmail()).isEqualTo(request.getEmail());
        assertThat(savedUser.getFirstName()).isEqualTo(request.getFirstName());
        assertThat(savedUser.getLastName()).isEqualTo(request.getLastName());
        assertThat(savedUser.getRole()).isEqualTo(request.getRole());
        assertThat(savedUser.getAge()).isEqualTo(request.getAge());
        assertThat(savedUser.getAddress()).isEqualTo(request.getAddress());

        // and: the right service called based on the role
        if (role == CUSTOMER) {
            verify(customerService).createCustomer(any(ApplicationUser.class));
            verify(personalTrainerService, never()).createTrainer(any(ApplicationUser.class));
        } else {
            verify(personalTrainerService).createTrainer(any(ApplicationUser.class));
            verify(customerService, never()).createCustomer(any(ApplicationUser.class));
        }
    }
```

Comment: This is not the correct forum for this question. I suggest you move it to [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).  Otherwise, the community will eventually close your question for being off topic.

Comment: No @hfontanez , requests to re-write code are off-topic for [codereview.se].

Comment: I'd consider splitting this in two. One runs with only role CUSTOMER, the other with all other roles; that can be done using `@EnumSource(value = Role.class, names = "CUSTOMER", mode = EXCLUDE)`. You can probably move most of the shared code to some private utility methods.

Comment: @Alex_Pap The question got downvoted most likely for the reason I mentioned before (it wasn't me, btw).

Comment: @TobySpeight it might be off topic there, but it is definitely more off topic here. If you have a better suggestion, why don't you share it?